# Why does Hive nested query statement require an alias?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm studying for the Hortonworks Developer certification and one exercise in the practice exam asks to create a table from several nested queries.

It's not clear to me why the following statement gives an error:

```
SELECT * FROM (nested queries);
```

While this statement works as expected:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (nested queries) AS a;
```

Comment: As far as my understanding the hive interpreter decodes the query string in reverse i.e last statement first and so on, so in order to analyse the query for execution it needs a name. If you run the explain query command you could see how the query plan takes place for more insights.

Comment: [The SubQuery](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)  has to be given a name because every table in a FROM clause must have a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table inside the from clause should have a name and because of that reason nested query inside from clause without alias throws error.

Read [Hive Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) for detailed description.